# Node.js module.exports not exporting the whole object

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use [sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com/) with express. The models are organized into multiple directories.

`Users(directory)`

```
users.js
profile.js
...
```

`Articles`

```
article.js
comments.js
...
```

I've modified the [sequelize-express](https://github.com/jpotts18/mean-stack-relational/blob/master/config/sequelize.js) example to loop through subdirectories and import the models using promises.

sequelize_init.js

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
_ = require('lodash'),
config = require('./auth-config'),
Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
glob = require('glob'),
Q = require('q'),
db = {};

var sequelize;

function getGlobbedModels() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    glob('./config/sequelize/models/**/*.js', function(err, files) {
        if(err)
            deferred.reject('Glob Error' + err);
        else
            deferred.resolve(files);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

function importModels(models){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    for (var i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(!i) {
            deferred.resolve('Successfully Required');
        }
        var model = sequelize.import(path.resolve(models[i]));
        db[model.name] = model;
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

function associateModels(resp) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var models = Object.keys(db);
    for (var i = models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(!i) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        if(db[models[i]].options.hasOwnProperty('associate')) {
            db[models[i]].options.associate(db);
        }
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

function synchronize() {
    // Synchronizing any model changes with database. 
    sequelize
        .sync({
            force: process.env.FORCE_DB_SYNC
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.info('Database synchronized');
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.error('An error occurred: ', err);
        });
}

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION') {
    //Use production DB
}else {
    //Use local DB
    sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
}

getGlobbedModels()
    .then(importModels)
        .fail(function(err){
            console.error('importModels err ' + err);
        })
    .then(associateModels)
        .fail(function(err){
            console.error('associateModels err' + err);
        })
    .then(synchronize)
        .fail(function(err){
            console.error('synchronize err' + err);
        });

// assign the sequelize variables to the db object and returning the db. 
module.exports = _.extend({
    sequelize: sequelize,
    Sequelize: Sequelize
}, db);
```

And in my app.js file, I'm requiring the below code but the models are undefined when exported to the require call. I've verified the above db object and the models are successfully required but are not exported to the require call.

app.js

```
var models = require('./sequelize_init.js');
models.User.findAll().then(); // Throws undefined error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are imported, associated, etc. asynchronously, long after `module.exports` is set, so `db` is still an empty object when you merge it at the end of your module.

One solution to this is to instead export an initialization function that takes a callback that is called once all of your initialization steps are complete. For example:

**sequelize_init.js**

```
// ...

module.exports = function(cb) {
  getGlobbedModels()
      .then(importModels)
          .fail(cb)
      .then(associateModels)
          .fail(cb)
      .then(synchronize)
          .fail(cb)
      .then(function() {
        cb(null, _.extend({
          sequelize: sequelize,
          Sequelize: Sequelize
        }, db));
      });
};
```

**app.js**

```
var init = require('./sequelize_init.js');
init(function(err, models) {
  if (err) throw err;

  models.User.findAll().then();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Would you suggest an alternate approach to the promise based approach or improvements to the above code? I'm requiring the init file in every controller to access the model

Comment: It's a matter of preference. If you want to stay strictly with Promises, you could export a Promise instead of an init function, that gets resolved with the value of `_.extend(...)`.